# How to sort strings in a list based on a integer part?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to write a function which sorts strings in a list by their integer part. These sorted strings will be used later to move some variables in a desired manner in `pandas` dataframe. **This function needs to do everything. In other words it overwrites the given list as a return**. Below you can find something I tried:

```
import re
import pandas

wholeregex = r"^[o][0-9]+"  # e.g. "o1", "o9", "o10" etc.
intregexkey = r"^[o]([0-9]+)"  # so I'm looking for integer parts only
varslist = list(df.filter(regex=wholeregex).columns)  # df was defined somewhere before

# e.g. varslist = ["o3", "o8", "o10", "o1"]
#result should be varslist = ["o1", "o3", "o8", "o10"]

def strintkeysort(regex, m):
    lstreturn = []
    r = re.compile(regex)
    lstreturn = sorted(m, key=int(r.search(m).group(1)))
    return lstreturn

varslist = strintkeysort(intregexkey, varslist)
```

When I run this function I receive this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/script.py", line 130, in <module>
    varslist = strintkeysort(intregexkey, varslist)
  File "C:/path/script.py", line 127, in strintkeysort
    lstreturn = sorted(m, key=int(r.search(m).group(1)))
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

It's based on a @Ashwini Chaudhary's answer ([Sort list of strings by a part of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431052/sort-list-of-strings-by-a-part-of-the-string)). What makes me very confused is that when I tried to do this exactly in a way he presented it - everything was fine. So I decided to boost this function and do all at once (with no effect) as an excercise (**I'm new in Python**).

**On the other hand: is there any dedicated solution to do this in `pandas`?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/).

Comment: Could you show the sample input and output?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `sorted(df["col"].values, key=lambda el: int(re.match(r"o(\d+)", el).group(1)))`?

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang! It worked! However I'm just curious how this function would look like if written purely using basic library and ```re```.

Comment: @BillHuang - as I'm reasoning good you wrote a code to sort values in a column and my task is to sort a range of columns (not values).

Comment: @Grayrigel - I added something. Is it what you meant?