# How to convert whole list of string into integer using python

Tags: python-3.x

Having list like `l1=['abc.123','abc.456','abc.789','abc.153']`
I want to sort this list based on numbers which are suffixes. But for that reason I have to convert this string list into integer. How can we do that.

Desired output is : `l1= [abc.123,abc.153,abc.456,abc.789]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `sorted(my_lst, key = lambda x: x[-3:])` or even `sorted(my_lst, key = lambda x: int(x[-3:]))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort list of strings by a part of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431052/sort-list-of-strings-by-a-part-of-the-string)

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to sort on the integer value of the *part after the period*, not of the last three characters. This allows for strings with fewer or more digits.

```
sorted(my_lst, key = lambda x: int(x.split(".")[-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we know that the last 3 characters are digits we could do:

```
sorted(my_lst, key = lambda x: int(x[-3:]))
['abc.123', 'abc.153', 'abc.456', 'abc.789']
```

or even noting that the are 3 numeric characters, you can go ahead and use them:

```
sorted(my_lst, key = lambda x: x[-3:])
['abc.123', 'abc.153', 'abc.456', 'abc.789']
```

Comment: But this is not good practice to sort string based on the numbers because sort will not treat number as a digit it will treat them as a string so thats the reason first convert it into integer and the sort them .

Comment: @rrr. Look at my assumption. I am taking only the last 3 digits. Whether sorted as string/integer will be the same. Eg '000' is the smallest while '999' is the largest.

Comment: so I have to split the list

Comment: @rrr check the answe given below